# What authentication model should my application use?

Tags: c#, security, authentication

We have a SPA application that makes use of cookie-based authentication. The cookie is validated on the app server by checking the expiration time of the user's stored session in a database.

The client requirement is that each new tab/browser opened should force the user to log in on that new tab/browser instance, thus allowing the user to have multiple sessions open for concurrent work purposes. Closing a tab or signing out needs to expire the user's session for that specific tab and still keep the other sessions active. Refreshing a tab should obviously still keep the user logged in on that specific tab.

At the moment, we make use of a unique identifier to identify the specific tab with its accompanying cookie, in order to only clear the relevant cookie when the user logs out or closes the tab. This unique identifier is stored in Session Storage and gets passed as a header with each server request. This unique identifier is visible in the the browser URL, for the reason that when the tab is refreshed, that identifier is used to get the relevant cookie and authenticate it.

This whole process feels clunky and prone to bad security practice.

What type of authentication would be best to facilitate the client requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a very old-fashion and outdate requirement, to have separate sessions per tab. One approach is to let the backend redirect each new request to it, to its own unique per-tab sub-domain, so that each sub-domain can get its own independent set of cookies.

like

```
session1.mysite.com
session2.mysite.com
session3.mysite.com
session4.mysite.com
session5.mysite.com
```